# jquery.jscroll and removing div from main container

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm beginning my journey with jquery (thanks to django).

I'm using jquery.jscroll to lazy load next pages which work (now) flawlessly (thanks to adding doctyp html), and when I scroll down the page it work fine, the problem is when I don't scroll at all but use button to remove content I watch from page.

I tried a little *hack* with moving window by 1px which work but after few clicks move menu out of view - I would like to change that to something that works.

My code is:
html:

```
<div class="scroll" id="scroll">
        {% if is_paginated %}
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <center><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="last">more</a></center>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
</div>
<script>
$('.scroll').jscroll({
    autoTrigger: true,
    nextSelector: 'a:last',
    loadingHtml: '<center><img src="../../static/loading.gif" alt="Loading" /> Loading...</center>'
});
</script>
```

and my js file looks like this:

```
function hidePost(my_id)
{
   $.ajax({
        url: "/post/hide/" + my_id,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(msg) {
            $('#' + my_id).remove();
            $('.lazy').Lazy();
            window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + 1);
            return false;
        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus)
        {
           alert('Error Occured');
           alert(textStatus);
           alert(jqXHR);
        }
     });
}
```

This code work fine but `window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + 1);` give me scroll down and if i add `window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 1);` to move back up then it wont trigger `$('.scroll').jscroll` and I dont want to trigger `$('.scroll').jscroll` each time I hidePost because there is 25 posts per page and with hiding all i would pre-load 25 next pages.

Is there a way to simulate scroll (without moving window) or trigger jscroll only when the  is visable (as its doing now)?

Comment: Have you tried to just call `$('.scroll').jscroll();` where you need to trigger jscroll?

Comment: I did and it dosn't work;